# Filter Cartesian product so it fits in memory

Tags: python, lazy-evaluation, cartesian-product

I have a list of lists

`y = [[a, b, c], ...]`

I want to generate the Cartesian product between all of the lists. `itertools.product` in python does this but all at once so I can't hold them in memory.

I only need a subset of the output though. For arguments sake say only those that sum to 1. I need to sequentially obtain results so I can drop those that that are unneeded.

Essentially

```
[x for x in itertools.product(*y) if sum(x)==1]
```

where `itertools.product` does not eagerly evaluate.

Comment: `itertools.product` does **not** do them all at one (it's in the `itertools` module after all).

Comment: Is this meant to be a self-answered question? It seems the solution is right there in the question... Am I missing something? I mean, *"`itertools.product` __does not__ eagerly evaluate"*...

Comment: My condition was satisfied more times than expected so I saw a similar overhead

Comment: I don't understand if your goal is to save *something* to memory, or not at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just replace your square brackets with `(` and `)`: that will make your resulting expression a [generator](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/functional.html#generator-expressions-and-list-comprehensions) (that evaluates lazily) and not a list (that will have all of its content in memory).

```
(x for x in itertools.product(*y) if sum(x)==1)
```

Answer (score 1):

[`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) is already lazy. All functions in the `itertools` module are - they return an iterator, never lists. So just loop over the product and filter:

```py
for prod in itertools.product(*y):
    if sum(prod) == 1:
        print(filtered_result)
```

Alternatively, the built-in function [`filter(function, iterable)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) also:

> Construct[s] an iterator from those elements of *iterable* for which *function* returns true.

So you can also iterate over the derived filtered iterator from the product iterator:

```py
for filtered_result in filter(lambda x: sum(x) == 1, product(*y)):
    print(filtered_result)
```